# Nested Select errors with ORA-00913: too many values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Full Disclosure: absolutely newb coder learning as I go.  I've written the following select routine which throws an ORA-00913: too many values error at Line 13 column 18 (the second nested select statement for address info).  I've searched and read the most simple suggestions (be certain your parentheses match or look for typos) to explicitly looking at the WHERE clause, using AS or other suggestions but no love so far.

```
select distinct  
   (select u.misc_data 
              from ps_name_miscnmbr u                                       
              where (u.misc_id = 'RFID') and u.name_id = cn.name_id) RFID,
            cn.dflt_id StudentIdNumber,                                  
            cn.first_name FirstName,
            cn.last_name LastName,
            cn.middle_name MiddleName,
            'pot: 100' as CollegeCode,
            to_char (cn.date_birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DateOfBirth,
            p.area_code,
            p.phone_no,
            (select  a.line1 StreetAddress1,
                     a.line2 StreetAddress2,
                     a.city City,
                     a.stat_id ST,
                     a.postal Zip
                from co_v_dflt_addr a
                where (a.adty_id in ('LOCL','HOME') and a.name_id = cn.name_id)),
            e.email_address Email                       
    from co_name cn,
         sr_v_enroll s,
         co_name_demo d,
         co_v_name_email e,
         co_v_name_phone1 p
    where s.term_id in ('201701', '201702', '201703') 
        and s.name_id = cn.name_id
        and d.name_id = cn.name_id
        and e.name_id = cn.name_id
        and p.name_id = cn.name_id
order by LastName
```

When I isolate that second nested Select statement for addresses and run it by itself it executes and produces the columns/records that I expected.

```
(select distinct         cn.name_id,
                     a.line1 StreetAddress1,
                     a.line2 StreetAddress2,
                     a.city City,
                     a.stat_id State,
                     a.postal Zip
                from co_v_dflt_addr a,
                     co_name cn
                where (a.adty_id in ('LOCL','HOME') and a.name_id = cn.name_id))
```

When I comment out that entire selection subquery for addresses, the remainder of the routine also executes and produces the columns/records that I expected.

```
select distinct  
   (select u.misc_data 
              from ps_name_miscnmbr u                                       
              where (u.misc_id = 'RFID') and u.name_id = cn.name_id) RFID,
            cn.dflt_id StudentIdNumber,                                  
            cn.first_name FirstName,
            cn.last_name LastName,
            cn.middle_name MiddleName,
            'pot: 100' as CollegeCode,
            to_char (cn.date_birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DateOfBirth,
            p.area_code,
            p.phone_no,
            e.email_address Email                       
    from co_name cn,
         sr_v_enroll s,
         co_name_demo d,
         co_v_name_email e,
         co_v_name_phone1 p
    where s.term_id in ('201701', '201702', '201703') 
        and s.name_id = cn.name_id
        and d.name_id = cn.name_id
        and e.name_id = cn.name_id
        and p.name_id = cn.name_id
order by LastName
```

Can someone offer a rookie a helpful tip here?  I've been going round and round trying things that aren't getting me to the finish line.

Thanks

Comment: You inner query is part of `SELECT`, so you can only have a single value.  If your inner query produces rows and columns, then it obviously won't work.

Comment: Also use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 20 years!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if you are writing a report for an education entity of some sort.  As stated above, the design choice is up to you, however, I have found that our faculty/staff like to have as much information as possible in a single line for each student record.  I would recommend the below (untested code, but shows you how to join the tables and return results even if no data exists without not returning a record for the student).  Also, as stated above, you are attempting to return multiple address records in the Scalar Subquery, but the multiple results can not fit into one column for each respective result set (since it returns both home and local address, but only has one column to put it into it fails).  Here is something to review and try (this would probably work in MSSQL, not sure about Oracle):

```
select
distinct
u.misc_dta as StudentIDNumber,
cn.dflt_id StudentIdNumber,                                  
cn.first_name FirstName,
cn.last_name LastName,
cn.middle_name MiddleName,
'pot: 100' as CollegeCode,
to_char (cn.date_birth, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DateOfBirth,
p.area_code,
p.phone_no,
h.line1 as HomeStreetAddress1,
h.line2 as HomeStreetAddress2,
h.city as HomeCity,
h.stat_id HomeST,
h.postal HomeZIP,
l.line1 as LocalStreetAddress1,
l.line2 as LocalStreetAddress2,
l.city as LocalCity,
l.stat_id LocalST,
l.postal LocalZIP,
e.email_address Email


from
co_name cn
left join
s_v_enroll s on cn.name_id = s.name_id
left join
co_name_demo d on cn.name_id = d.name_id
left join
co_v_name_email e on cn.name_id = e.name_id
left join
co_v_name_phone1 p on cn.name_id = p.name_id
left join
co_v_dflt_addra h on cn.name_id = h.name_id and h.adty_id = 'HOME'
left join
co_v_dflt_addra l on cn.name_id = l.name_id and h.adty_id = 'LOCL'
left join
ps_name_miscnbr as u on cn.name_id = u.name_id and u.misc_id = 'RFID'


where
s.term_id in ('201701', '201702', '201703') 

order by
cn.last_name
```

Comment: Thanks B. Baum (you're correct , it's a small post-secondary) for the suggested code (it works!), but also thanks to Zynon and Eric the Impaler for your hints/suggestions.  It is ALL helpful to a beginner.  My previous context was only script examples written by a predecessor. I was unaware that Joins Are Your Friend, didn't know where or how to use them, nor knew what a "Scalar Subquery" was.  Administrative types hear "IT" and think it's all the same work (how this landed in my lap).  Many thanks for your valuable time and gracious input.  You are restoring faith in humanity.  :)

Comment: You're welcome!  I use a lot of "LEFT JOIN" commands in my sql data because our faculty/staff want the columns, even if there is no data.  As long as data returns from the first table (co_name) then you will get columns for the rest.  Take a look at INNER JOIN and RIGHT JOIN as well.  A good resource is w3schools.com/sql for beginners.  I understand the "well you work in IT so you can do it concept".  We do not all do the same job, and SQL/programming is a really specialized scope...sadly, administration does not always understand this.

Answer (score 1):

Your sub query in the select statement returns potentially too many rows. When you use a sub query like that it needs to only ever return one row.

In this case, you probably should join the table to the rest of the query, using outer join if there is a possibility of no addresses returning. But this will bring back two rows if they have both a 'LOCL' and 'HOME' address. That design choice is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, **Scalar Subqueries** must return 1 row at most. Could be zero rows, or one row; never two or more.

The subquery you are showing:

```
select  a.line1 StreetAddress1,
                 a.line2 StreetAddress2,
                 a.city City,
                 a.stat_id ST,
                 a.postal Zip
            from co_v_dflt_addr a
            where (a.adty_id in ('LOCL','HOME') and a.name_id = cn.name_id)
```

is called a "Scalar Subquery" since it's typed as a "column" of the `SELECT`.

Oracle is complaining that this query is returning more than a single row, and that's an error. When you use Scalar Subqueries you must ensure there's at most one returned row for it, maybe by querying using the primary key or another unique key.